# Como hacer un mensaje multilinea en input con Python?

Tags: python, while

Me falta que salga el mensaje multilinea

```
print("Ingrese su mensaje:")


while (s := input()):
print(s)
```

El resultado debe de ser así

```
Ingrese su mensaje:

hola mundo
test de multi
lineas

hola mundo 
test de multi
lineas
```

La segunda parte es lo que debe de imprimir el programa.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130191/discussion-on-question-by-shon-casper-como-hacer-un-mensaje-multilinea-en-input).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se te pide es algo muy parecido a un shell interactivo, donde tendremos que recibir varias líneas, almacenar su valor y luego mostrar todo. Para este usaremos 2 cosas muy simples, la primera es una lista para guardar cada línea y la segunda un simple ciclo `while` tal y como lo haces tu.

Primero incializaremos una lista vacía, luego creamos un ciclo `while True` y solo parará cuando el usuario no ingrese nada dentro del input, es decir de un enter en el input sin haber puesto algo, ahí es cuando la cadena se considera como valor *falsy*

```py
datos = []
while True:
    entrada = input(">>> ")
    if entrada.strip(): #si contiene algo es True, de lo contrario False
        datos.append(entrada) #agregamos en caso contenga algo
    else:
        break #detenemos el ciclo for
#unimos todo mediante un salto de línea
print("\n".join(datos))
```

El método `join` une los elementos de un iterable mediante el caracter que se especifique, como en este caso cada elementos de la lista es una línea por separado entonces los unimos por un salto de línea.

```
>>> hola
>>> este es un test 
>>>  de multilínea
>>>
hola
este es un test 
  de multilínea
```